# Would it be possible to use JQuery Bootstrap framework along with Aurelia?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, aurelia

Would it be possible to use jQuery Bootstrap with Aurelia? There are some toggle buttons and other components I would like to use that come with Bootstrap.

So far, all of the examples I have seen are using jQuery UI along with Aurelia.

Comment: yes, in fact the skeleton uses this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the skeleton-navigation project. It uses bootstrap by default:

https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-es2016

The magic happens here

https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/skeleton-es2016/src/main.js#L1

```
import 'bootstrap';
```

Note that bootstrap is installed via JSPM.

Comment: So can i do an import $ from 'jquery' and start using JQuery bootstrap components , say $('#myModal').modal()  ?

Comment: correct, or you could simply leave $ in the global namespace

Comment: some examples uses import $ from 'bootstrap'; is that what I should do too ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that syntax. That might be for a boostrap+jquery build. Can't help you there.

Comment: Okay that was my original question., sorry i was not clear.using JQuery Bootstrap framework along with Aurelia.. I think that is the way i should do it.

Comment: As far as I know the Bootstrap 3 JavaScript components are jQuery plugins. So they just add on to jQuery and that's why you can use `import $ from 'bootstrap'. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996551/how-to-import-bootstrap-datetimepicker-into-aurelia-project also has this topic.

Comment: @VolkerRose thanks That make sense. But in case if i need to shim one more "global" JQuery Plugin with JSPM, say xxxPlugin, how does it work when i try to use import $ from xxxPlugin ?Can i still use import $ from bootstrap and avail all methods from the xxxPlugin ?

Comment: @user636525, that is a good point e.g. question, which I also want to know. Maybe it deserves its own place? Can you post it as a separate question?

Comment: @VolkerRose we just need to add one import $ , JQuery plugins adds their methods to the JQuery wrapper. I tested and its working fine.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089583/attach-multiple-jquery-plugins-onto-a-single-element

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks for letting me/us know :)